# Should mini-batches contain an even mix of classes or can this be random?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, mini-batch-gradient-descent

I'm creating mini-batches to put into a CNN. Is it best to try and get an even mix of classes into each mini-batch (Scenario 1), or can this/should this be a random assortment of my classes (Scenario 2)?

Scenario 1:

- I have 2 classes and a mini-batch size of 32. I should try and have 16 samples from each class in each mini-batch.

Scenario 2:

- Same as 1, but I have a random distribution of samples in each mini-batch. So this could be 20 of one class and 12 of the other. Or even 32 of one class and none of the other on occasion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, it should not matter.  As long as there are a large number of mini-batches and a good balance of classes within the training data.

Answer (score 0):

If you use minibatch gradient descent , we should do random sampling. I think using just one class may lead to bias

Comment: Sure thing. However, say I had 200 minibatches its quite likely that a small number of these would contain only one class. But, you suspect random is better than ensuring each has an even split of classes?